# What are the best sites online for understanding tumah and tahara

Tags: product-recommendation, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity

I'm speaking in general and not of the laws of Taharat Mishpacha. As a scientist I find Tumah and Taharah fascinating, but I haven't found anything on Taharot (at least in English) that's comparable to dafyomi.co.il (which focuses on the Talmud) for example.

One thing that would be awesome is if someone had a list of modern Kelim that are pure or mekabel tumah.

Comment: Someone’s Daf yomi blog had a great write up from several years ago